# In weight painting, I have at least two vertexes refusing to take zero weight

Tags: armature, weight-painting, pose-mode

I have *Auto Normalize* and *Falloff Shape > Projected* turned on and *Front Faces Only* turned off. I think it was not painting through the mesh. I have checked that the vertices are not overlapping and that I have tried clicking everywhere to get these two points to have zero weight. What is the solution?

[image]

Comment: Could you attach your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: How do I close this question? Found out that the mesh needed modifying as only one vertex was used that was shared between the toes.

Comment: Don't close this question, just attach the link to the question you found useful or just answer your own question to help others.

Answer (score 0):

My check list contained in my question omitted to add: make sure the mesh vertices are not connected. Found out the two points were joining the toes. Solution was to separate the toes by adding additional vertices.